# php redirect email to file

Tags: php, email

I am using php5.

Are there some settings or a simple php.ini directive that would redirect all the emails to a folder?

I want on the development machine to have all the emails generated by the system not sent to the actual receiver but put in a folder.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used to have some code like this (kinda pseudocode):

```
define ('DEBUG', true);
function send_email($to, $subject, $body) {
    if (DEBUG) {
        file_put_contents('some_folder/' . $to . date('dmY-His') . '.html', $body);
    }else{
        // Actual code to send email
    }
}
```

But i agree with others, it's easier/better to setup an development email account to receive those emails.

Comment: i went with this solution as there is not only one email adress that the server send emails to (users can register, ...)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you will be able to do something like this. Mails are sent by a mail server so it must be your mail server that writes them to a file instead of sending them.

Why not simply send it to a special development email?

Sample:

```
define('DEBUG', true);

if(DEBUG)
{
    // Override recipient
    $recipient = 'development@domain.tld';
}

// Send mail...
```

Comment: i guess i will go with this solution.

Answer (score 0):

No settings that I'm aware of in PHP itself. However, if you're using Postfix on your development server, here's a recipe I cooked up to redirect all outbound email to a single (local) address:

**/etc/postfix/main.cf**: (add this to the existing file, don't replace everything)

```
virtual_alias_maps = regexp:/etc/postfix/virtual
```

**/etc/postfix/virtual**:

```
/.*/ duskwuff@localhost
```

Answer (score 0):

You can configure your mail server to accept SMTP messages as normal, but make it unable to forward them onto another mail server. If your mail server supports it, make it redirect all messages to a postmaster account, or any other address of your choice.

This means that PHP will behave as normal, everything will appear to work straight away with the message, but it just won't go to the 'intended' recipient.

It also means that you can inspect headers (pretty much as they would normally appear), to support debugging.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this.  Basically, you need to define the sendmail command in your php.ini to point to a program or script which will save the mail locally.

One solution is this:
[Catch emails with php script](http://martinvalasek.com/blog/how-to-catch-emails-sent-with-php-on-your-local-server)

Another is this:

[Mail catcher](http://mailcatcher.me/)